# Unreported exception must be caught or declared to be thrown:

Tags: java, lombok

I have this code which although have the Lombok `SneakyThrows` annotation, the compiler still complains that `Error:(65, 58) java: unreported exception java.rmi.RemoteException; must be caught or declared to be thrown:`

```
@SneakyThrows
@Override
public Optional<Boolean> unregister() throws RemoteException {
    if(registry != null) {
      Arrays.asList(registry.list()).forEach(className -> {
        registry.unbind(className);
      });
    }
    return Optional.of(true);
}
```

The method that calls this method above is this:

```
@SneakyThrows
public void stopDatabase() {
    if(registrar == null) {
      LOG.error("Database has not started");
    } else {
      registrar.unregister();
    }
}
```

**Updating the code to this (solves the issue)**
but we don't want to change to using for-loop like this:

```
@SneakyThrows
@Override
public Optional<Boolean> unregister() {
       if (registry != null) {
           String[] classNames = registry.list();
           for(int i=0;i<classNames.length;i++) {
              registry.unbind(classNames[i]);
           }
      }
      return Optional.of(true);
}
```

Comment: do the method which call unregister() have try catch or throws RemoteException define ?

Comment: try   `@SneakyThrows (RemoteException.class)`

Comment: @VietDD the method that calls `unregister` also have `SneakyThrows` annotation on it

Comment: how about add try catch into stopDatabase() ? (wrap the if {} else{})

Comment: because registrar.unregister(); can throw the RemoteException, you need to catch it or throw it again to the method which call stopDatabase() (at least 1 method need to catch the RemoteException)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is complaining because you're telling it `unregister()` throws a checked exception. Remove the `throws RemoteException` from the method declaration so Lombok can hide the checked exception from the compiler.

Example usage: https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows

Comment: Also, when reading the linked web page, make note about the common uses for SneakyThrows. It's intended to make handling of unnecessary exception declarations easier. RemoteException is not an unnecessary exception and you should handle it instead of trying to hide it. Lombok is the loaded assault rifle of programming tools. It should never be placed in the hands of untrained programmers.

Comment: Even removing the Exceptions from the declaration did not solve the problem

Comment: I wonder if the Lombok integration is working correctly. Here's a guide for setting it up: https://projectlombok.org/setup/overview